# Combine two observables and return values as List even when one Observable emits onError

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to combine two observables into list of objects and viewing it in the ViewModel. I'm doing it by using retrofit function which returns `Observable<TeamResponse>` . I want to call the function twice , but the function may emmit error when no object has been found in the backend API .

I tried using this :

```
val suggestedTeamsList = ArrayList<TeamResponse>()

Observable.just(teamUseCase.getTeamByUserId(player1ID), teamUseCase.getTeamByUserId(player2ID))
    .flatMap {
        return@flatMap it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(object: Observer<TeamResponse> {
            override fun onComplete() {
                suggestedTeams.postValue(suggestedTeamsList)
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

            }

            override fun onNext(t: TeamResponse) {
                Log.d("TEST",t.teamName)
                suggestedTeamsList.add(t)
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Log.d("TEST",e.message)
                suggestedTeams.postValue(suggestedTeamsList)
            }
        })
```

and it works but I would prefer to get a result as a list even when one function emits onError , in that case the List would have just 1 object. Or maybe someone has a better idea how to handle it with good approach ? As there may be a case where the methods return in both situations onError

Comment: create your two observables & combine with zip Single.zip(observable1,observable2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use Observable.zip. EG:

```
val teamResponse = TeamResponse()

fun loadPlayers() {

    val first = teamUseCase.getTeamByUserId(player1ID)
    .onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable -> Observable.just( teamResponse ) }

   val second = teamUseCase.getTeamByUserId(player2ID)
    .onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable -> Observable.just( teamResponse ) }

   Observable.zip(first, second, BiFunction<TeamResponse, TeamResponse, List<TeamResponse>> { t1, t2 ->
       val suggestedTeamsList = mutableListOf<TeamResponse>()
       if (t1 !== teamResponse) {
           suggestedTeamsList.add(t1)
       }
       if (t2 !== teamResponse) {
           suggestedTeamsList.add(t2)
       }
       suggestedTeamsList
    })
   .subscribeOn()
}
```

Comment: this looks nice :) But can you provide more details into this method ? What should i put into Observable.just() inside onErrorResumeNext  and also what is the rest of zip function ? Any hints ? :)

Comment: `onErrorResumeNext` returns an `Observable` . You could create a fake version of `TeamrResponse` and return that. Inside the `BiFunction` you can check if the the response(s) are the fake or the real one and act accordingly

Comment: What do you mean with fake version of TeamResponse ?

Comment: something that you instantiate manually, like a constant - EG. `val teamResponseA = TeamResponse()`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really do not understand what you mean here, could u provide more code into your answer ?